# EF Core - search properties by string

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table with a few hundred columns, and from my client I'm passing multiple 'search' objects to the server used to query this table. Each search object contains a search term, and the name of the property to match it against.

I'm not sure how to use reflection here to query the property using EF Core. I have tried the following but it didn't like it.

```
var prop = <ENTITYTYPE>.GetProperty(search.Property);

query = context.<ENTITY>.Where(x => (string)prop.GetValue(x) == search.SearchTerm);
```

I'm thinking that I might have to construct a raw SQL query, but I would love to know if there's a way I can jig it so that EF Core creates the query itself. When I do a `.ToList()` on the above, it says that the query cannot be translated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't use reflection in an EF Core query or pass properties by name like this. `Where` can work with any valid expression so you could rewrite your code to pass `Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>` as filters instead of strings. You could also use the [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) package to parse string expressions but this loses any kind of compile-time checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic realization which should push you in the right direction:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> AddFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, string searchTerm)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var propExpression = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
    
    object value = searchTerm;
    if (propExpression.Type != typeof(string))
        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, propExpression.Type);

    var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            propExpression,
            Expression.Constant(value)
        ),
        param
    );

    return query.Where(filterLambda);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I got it working with Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This method should work well for single instance entities.

```
public IQueryable<T> GetBySearchTerm(IQueryable<T> queryable, string search)
{
    void GenerateLambda<T>(IProperty columnProp, MethodInfo methodInfo, List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> expressions)
    {
        if (columnProp.ClrType == typeof(string))
        {
            // Define the parameter
            ParameterExpression xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            // Create the expression representing what column to do the search on
            MemberExpression colExpr = Expression.Property(xParam, columnProp.Name);
            // Create a constant representing the search value
            ConstantExpression constExpr = Expression.Constant(search);
            // Generate a method body that represents "column contains search"
            MethodCallExpression lambdaBody = Expression.Call(colExpr, methodInfo, constExpr);
            // Convert the full expression into a useable query predicate
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(lambdaBody, xParam);
            expressions.Add(lambda);
        }
    }

    T thisEntityBaseModel = new T();
   
    IEntityType set = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().First(x => x.ClrType.Name.ToUpper() == thisEntityBaseModel.ModelName.ToUpper());
    List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicateArray = new List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();

    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    
    foreach (IProperty columnProp in set.GetProperties())
    {
        GenerateLambda(typeof(T), columnProp, containsMethod, predicateArray);
    }


    // This performs an "OR" method on the predicates, since by default it wants to do "AND"
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
    foreach (Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression in predicateArray) {
        predicate = predicate.Or(expression);
    }

    // Process the ors
    return (queryable.Where(predicate));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not recommended to use, see comments
I tried sample below and it works for me

```
private void Test()
{

    Type myType = typeof(AktivEvents);

    PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty("AutoReplyMessage");

    Func<AktivEvents, bool> func = (e) => (string)myPropInfo.GetValue(e) == "asdasd";


    var query = _dbService.AktivEvents.GetAll()
        .Where(func)
        .ToList();
}
```

It obviosly dirty but the idea is working, with dependecies

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Comment: You aren't using EF at all. Whatever `GetAll()` is, it returns all the data instead of a `DbSet`. It's simply not possible to translate a Reflection call into SQL. And loading everything in memory is no solution at all. It may work for 10 rows but not for tables with 1000 or 100K rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use repository pattern https://codewithshadman.com/repository-pattern-csharp/
and I tested sample on my project with database and it works

Comment: No it doesn't. That **anti**pattern loaded all 10/100K/1M rows in memory. After that, you're using LINQ-to-Objects. Loading everything in memory is unacceptable for production code. Not only does this waste RAM on the client, it also delays returning results until everything is loaded and worse, locks the entire table until all the data is loaded. Even if only a single row was needed. The last part can cause performance problems for the entire database and even deadlocks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah I checked it, you right

Comment: The article you linked to doesn't have a `GetAll()`. It uses `Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>` to pass arbitrary filters. The `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` classes and methods are essentially DbSet and DbContext renamed because DbSet is *already* a Repository and DbContext is *already* a Unit-of-Work